# NameError: uninitialized constant Rails::TestTask

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task, rakefile

I put this code inside my Rakefile in order to be able to run tests from an additional folder "test/classes" (not just from test/models, test/controllers etc):

```
# Adding test/classes directory to rake test.
namespace :test do # line 9
  desc "Test tests/classes/* code"
  Rails::TestTask.new(parsers: 'test:prepare') do |t| # line 11
    t.pattern = 'test/classes/**/*_test.rb'
  end
end

Rake::Task['test:run'].enhance ["test:classes"]
```

This code works perfectly when I run `rails test`.

But when I run `rails db:migrate`, I get this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Rails::TestTask
/Users/Developer/project/Rakefile:11:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/Developer/project/Rakefile:9:in `<top (required)>'
```

What do I do to get rid of the error, but still be able to load test files from

Answer (score 9):

insert

```
require 'rake/testtask'
```

into Rakefile

Comment: I had to do this and also rename `Rails::TestTask` to `Rake::TestTask` as @pdobb suggested.

Answer (score 4):

I saw this during a Rails 5.2 upgrade (from Rails 4.2). The fix for me was to rename `Rails::TestTask` to `Rake::TestTask` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

#### As of 2021

On your tests' setup, you can load your task:

```rb
before { Rails.application.load_tasks }
```

Then you invoke the task inside your test with:

```rb
Rake.application.invoke_task "namespace:task_name"
```

#### Sample code

Let's say you want to test the rake task below:

```rb
# lib/tasks/notifications.rake

namespace :notifications do
  desc "This task is called by the Heroku scheduler add-on"
  task properties_created: :environment do
    Account.all.each { |account| AccountMailer.properties_created(account).deliver } if Property.yesterday.any?
  end
end
```

Can be tested with:

```rb
# test/tasks/notifications_test.rb

require "test_helper"

class NotificationsTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include ActionMailer::TestHelper

  before { Rails.application.load_tasks }

  it "does not send email if no property created yesterday" do
    account = create(:account)
    create(:property, created_at: 2.days.ago, account: account)
    assert_emails(0) { Rake.application.invoke_task "notifications:properties_created" }
  end
end
```